# MaxLength in TextBox is not respected if AcceptsReturn=True

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

Does anyone find solution to problem with TextBox field where it definition look like this:

```
<TextBox MaxLength="10" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
```

in above case user shouldn't be able to enter more then 10 characters and it works as long he do not use "Enter". As soon he use enter to brake lines then TextBox will let him type +2 more character per line. 
So it looks that method responsible for respecting "MaxLength" attribute ignores "CR LF" :( 
Any suggestion how to overcome that problem are really welcome.

Comment: Which version of WPF are you using?

Comment: This is not WPF but WinRT.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution to that problem. It is not perfect but it does the job.

What I used is a converter with remove "\r" character from the text with user enter:

```
public class RemoveLineFeedCharConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value; //do not convert in that direction
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var text = (string) value;
        return text.Replace("\r", ""); //remove line feed character
    }
}
```

as stated, this is not perfect but at least make that text entered is shorter then MaxLength.

Hope that this will help someone

regards
MG

Answer (score 0):

I did this without a converter. If you are using two-way binding, like the following:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TextBoxText, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="10" AcceptsReturns="True"/>
```

Then you can apply a similar idea to the set function of the bound property:

```
private string _textboxtext;
public string TextBoxText 
{
    get{return _textboxtext;} 
    set
    {
        _textboxtext=value.Replace("\r",""); 
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```